# Attributary Dictionary Element in Python - Dict.Element - PyTricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I want to print `apple`'s value `1234` but not using `Dict['apple']` but using `Dict.apple` in Python 3. Is there any way to do this? We can use any other Data formats like: tuples or list. Just suggest me how can we do this in Python.

```
Dict = { 'apple':'1234'}
```

Comment: You can do this `Dict.get('apple')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but it's not worth the hassle.

Here's one solution that uses the builtin `namedtuple` class:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Dict = { 'apple':'1234'}

MyTupleClass = namedtuple('MyTupleClass', Dict)
my_tuple = MyTupleClass(**Dict)

print(my_tuple.apple)
```

Another that subclassed `dict`:

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.__getitem__(item)

d = MyDict({'apple': '1234'})
print(d.apple)
```

Both are ugly & not worth the reduced readability.

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without creating classes like: `MyDict = {'a':1234}` ||| `dc = MyDict.__dict__` ||| `dc.a`

Comment: Probably not. In python, the indexing operator `[]` & the attribute operator `.` are very different (unlike in Javascript). And that's for good reason. To override that behaviour you need to define it in your own class.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
class CustomDict(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d

Dict = { 'apple':'1234'}
custom_dict = CustomDict(Dict)
print(custom_dict.apple)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without creating classes like: 

`MyDict = {'a':1234}` |||
`dc = MyDict.__dict__` ||| 
`dc.a`

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot guys! But I also found an answer for it.

```
from dotmap import DotMap
myDict = DotMap(a:'1234')

>> myDict.a
>> 1234
```

Comment: dotmap is not a standard python library, and if you can solve your problem without it with no trouble, you better not use it.

Comment: Yupp bro. You're true.